# HDD freezes Windows 10 when reading

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, freeze, mft, bootsector

My external hard drive (MAXTOR M3) run into issues lately.

At first I thought the MFT or boot sector got damaged somehow. Because the drive didn't show up at all, not even in the disk management. The drive didn't drop or had any other physical damage. But one time the drive showed up, although it made Windows crash/freeze. So the MFT must still exist or it wouldn't show all folders and files. I checked the computer's ports using a different drive and they work fine. I also checked the cable on another drive and it works. I used the cable of the other drive and suddenly folders showed up a second time, but again resulting in a crash. Later the drive continuously showed up, but immediately crashed when clicking on the drive icon in the explorer. I switched from front panel to the back of the computer and was able to browse the folders and secure/copy at least one very important file. But doing so the system was very very slow, almost to the point of freeze. Trying to get into another folder made it crash completely. Now I cannot get into it a third time. So my first assumption was that there is something wrong with the hardware of the drive. Possibly the USB port. I opened the external case and connected it directly (no USB). Still the same issue. The drive showed up in explorer, the system slows down (trying to read the data), never finishes it to the point of showing the folders and if I click on the drive that leads to a total freeze/crash. I know the files and MFT still exist, but Windows cannot access them.

After ruling out the USB port as the culprit, I am out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: Test the external drive with the manufacturer's drive diagnostics app or one of the third party apps     ........   https://www.lifewire.com/free-hard-drive-testing-programs-2626183

Comment: It's a common symptom for failing drives. Best way to deal with it is clone the drive using a tool that was designed for failing drives, ddrescue for example.